# How to measure Akka actors performance?

Tags: performance, akka, performance-testing, actor, akka-cluster

I am trying to measure the performance off all the akka actors involved in the system, focusing mainly on the duration of reply to messages.

Is there any way to do this automatically or I should rely on the information lgged on preStart and preStop?

Comment: logging all the akka lifecycle and message are possible: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/logging.html#Auxiliary_logging_options , but I think the performance measuring is different problem.

Comment: In the beggining, I  am interested about the duration of a reply. I think I could build something around loggin, but i was asking whether there is a solution already.

Comment: What the definition of the term "duration of a reply"?

Comment: We create actors on-the fly for only one processing. For atomic acctors that would be the duration between receiving the message and sending back the result of their processing to their parrent.

Comment: Maybe utilizing a well established library could be of any help?
http://metrics.dropwizard.io
http://kamon.io

Answer (score 1):

One way is to configure Kamon for akka and use StatsD or some other reporter backend.